# GPO limited by system version (Windows Server 2012)?

Tags: bandwidth, wsus, bits

Windows Server 2012

I want to enable this local GPO:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkgBx.png]

Where it says "Supported on: Windows 7 or computers with BITS 3.5 installed" got me confused, because Windows Server 2012 has BITS 7.6 installed.

Is this GPO going to have any effect? I enabled it, but couldn't feel any difference in network bandwidth consumption.

Comment: `Is this GPO going to have any effect? I enabled it, but couldn't feel any difference in network bandwidth consumption.` - How exactly are you "feeling" network bandwidth consumption? How are you measuring it? Are you looking specifically at BITS network traffic?

Comment: I was just checking network traffic, but I don't know if WSUS is considered background traffic or not, because I enabled the GPO but the internet was still slow. Does it take a while to have any effect? Thanks

Comment: Saying that you were just "checking" network traffic is way too vague a statement as to have any real meaning. How exactly are you "checking" this traffic? What baseline are you comparing it to? Is your entire motivation for enabling this GPO setting due to the fact that your internet connection is slow? If so, that seems like a wildly random thing to do.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I wasn't clear enough. I'm checking with Task Manager, and the internet in the office started to get slow after I enabled WSUS to download updates. As it is a fresh WSUS install, a lot of updates are being downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft forgot to update the description on that one - it applies to all versions with BITS 3.5 or later installed. So yes - it would apply to Windows Server 2012.

You say that you don't see any effect after applying the policy - did you run gpupdate after editing the policy? Are you checking the actual BITS transfers?

Use Performance Monitor to track the BITS traffic, or use the various tools available (bitsadmin or the BITS powershell modules)

Comment: Good to know, I'll enable this policy on my server to stop consuming my bandwidth during work hours. I'll check Performance Monitor to track BITS traffic, thanks! Do you know if WSUS is considered BITS traffic?

Comment: @VitorGatti Client-to-Server traffic (as in your desktop clients using WSUS) are using BITS. I'm not sure how WSUS downloads updates from the Update Catalog, but I would _guess_ that it's WSUS. Just use get-bitstransfer when WSUS is downloading...